# Could not read until the end sequence number of the range

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have a spark streaming application which reads data from Kinesis, processes it and sends the result into Elasticsearch. It was working fine But it suddenly started throwing the following error while reading data from Kinesis.

**org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not read until the end sequence number of the range: SequenceNumberRange**(stream-name,shardId-000000000001,49564147249261667294290839417071178182684353736229257490,49562657249261966294290839428797758632946257692951838994)

I appreciate your help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: were you able to proceed or find solution ?